# Merge two arrays with OpenMP but no speedup

Tags: c, openmp

I have to merge two arrays with OpenMP. The idea is to split the arrays in p segments with co-ranking (where p is the amount of processors), and then give each processor on of these segments to merge.

The problem, there is no speedup at all compared to a non-parallel merge of the two arrays.

I checked if the bounds in which the `a` and `b` arrays are split are correct, and to my understanding they are. The `coRank` function ranks the `a` value in `c` in `b` and `a`, and to my understanding it seems correct and should not cause the problem. If we have a look in Windows Task Manager CPU usage, all CPU cores have the same spike when the program is launched, so I assume all CPUs actually get to do something. The merged array is correct, but it takes as long as a sequential merge.

```
void merge(array_t a[], long x, array_t b[], long y, array_t c[]) {
//split the a and b arrays with co-ranking
    int cores = omp_get_max_threads();
    long *startsInA = (long *)malloc(sizeof(long) * cores);
    long *startsInB = (long *)malloc(sizeof(long) * cores);

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < cores; i++){
        coRank((i*(x+y)/cores),a,x,b,y,&startsInA[i],&startsInB[i]);
    }
//do a sequential merge for each segment-pair
  #pragma omp parallel private(a,b)
  {
    int index = omp_get_thread_num();
    long lowerBoundA = startsInA[index];
    long lowerBoundB = startsInB[index];
    int upperBoundA;
    int upperBoundB;
    if(index < cores - 1){
        upperBoundA = startsInA[index+1];
        upperBoundB = startsInB[index+1];
    } else {
        upperBoundA = x;
        upperBoundB = y;
    }
    seq_merge1((a+lowerBoundA),upperBoundA-lowerBoundA, (b+lowerBoundB),upperBoundB-lowerBoundB,c+lowerBoundA+lowerBoundB);
  }
  free(startsInA);
  free(startsInB);
}
```

The output of the merge function is correct, but it should be faster then sequential merge, which it is not.

Comment: Parallelization introduces overhead, so (for that among other reasons)  it is not guaranteed to yield a speedup.  On what basis, then, do you claim that the parallel version should be faster?

Comment: In your case, however, you also have the *explicit* overhead of allocating memory and computing the co-ranking, on top of all the implicit overhead of managing multiple threads.  I can't tell how expensive the co-ranking is, but I'd guess its cost is a substantial fraction of the cost of a merge.  Moreover, although you're doing it in parallel, it's not clear to me how you can do that correctly, as it seems like there must either be data dependencies or problems related to the distribution of the inputs.

Comment: it is an assignment and we should get more then 10 times the speed in some cases, we are running this on a really huge machine with 32 cores an really large input arrays (a.lenght = b.lenght = 100.000.000). But still, the more cores we add, the slower the programm gets. We tried to measure the time that the co-ranking takes, but the parallel part is causing more than 99% of the runtime.

Could you elaborate how to fix the (potential) data dependency/distribution issues?

Comment: You mean *the merges* are taking 99% of the runtime, I presume.  The co-ranking is also a parallel part.  Have you checked that the the co-ranking produces correct results?  One plausible reason for the merge taking more time than you think it should would be that it is doing more work than you think it does.

Comment: As for data dependencies, that's irrelevant if your co-ranking is in fact spending minimal time and producing correct results.  With respect to distribution issues, the point is that if the distribution of values to be merged results in most of them being assigned to one segment pair, then the parallelization will give you little wall-time advantage to offset the inherent overhead.  The way to fix *that*, if you can do, is to make sure the situation does not arise.

Comment: The coranking assures that all segments have an equal amount of values, and debugging the boundaries, this is true.